# Angular momentum operator: converting derivatives to spherical polar

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, differentiation

Given, for example,

$$    L_x=-i\hbar\left( y\dfrac{\partial}{\partial z}-z\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}   \right) ~~,$$

I want to convert the expression to polar coordinates.  I have

\begin{align}
x&=r\sin\theta\cos\phi\\
y&=r\sin\theta\sin\phi\\
z&=r\cos\theta
\end{align}

and I need to come up with the derivatives converted to polar coordinates.  I do not recall how to do this and it seems like I am going about it the excessively complicated way to invoke a trial function $f$ for a chain rule derivation

$$ df=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial r}dr+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}d\theta+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial \phi}d\phi~~. $$

I can extend this to, for example,

$$ \dfrac{d}{dz}f=\bigg(\dfrac{\partial  r}{\partial z}\dfrac{\partial  }{\partial r}+\dfrac{\partial \theta }{\partial z}\dfrac{\partial  }{\partial \theta}+\dfrac{\partial  \phi}{\partial z}\dfrac{\partial  }{\partial \phi}\bigg)f~~, $$

but then I have to take derivatives of

\begin{align}
r&=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\\
\theta&=\cos^{-1}\bigg(\cfrac{z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\bigg)\\
\phi&=\tan^{-1}\bigg(\cfrac{y}{x}\bigg)~~.
\end{align}

which seems unnecessary and too complicated compared to my memory of this being a simple conversion.  Is there a quicker, better way which I have forgotten?  Even starting the other way with

$$ df=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial z}dz~~, $$

seems too long.  I will be able to take the derivatives of the simpler functions but I'll still have to solve a system of equations.  I feel like there is some very simple method I'm forgetting.

Comment: https://quantummechanics.ucsd.edu/ph130a/130_notes/node216.html